# git: versioning a GNU/Linux distribution

Tags: git

I'm working on a custom version of a GNU/Linux live distribution. I need to add/remove packages, edit scripts...
I work in an unsquashed filesystem (squashfs-root/) used as root for chroot.
I'm wondering which is the best way to manage my work. Should I create a git repo and add squashfs-root/?
My main fear is messing up chroot env and cannot go back to a working version.
Thanks,
hamen

**UPDATE**:
I'll give a try to rdiff-backup. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with git (and other source control suites) is that it doesn't handle permissions and special files very well.

[etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) is a set of scripts on top of git to manage `/etc`. That can already provide you with much security.

Finally, you say you're running from a `chroot()`. This would allow you easy backups from outside of the chroot, e.g. with [rdiff-backup](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/non-gnu/rdiff-backup/), which creates nice compact on-disk representation while still allowing you to browse the most recent version directly.

Comment: Actually I thought to manual backups, but squashfs-root/ is 1.3G. Has rdiff-backup some "folder yesterday snapshot" feature?

Answer (score 1):

Automate everything you do and just version the scripts you use to create your distribution. That way you can always re-create your distribution in case you messed something up.

Comment: Scenario: current live distro has 2.6.26 kernel. I mount squashfs-root, choroot it, install 2.6.29 kernel sources, recompile kernel, add new kernel to squashfs-root, compress squashfs-root, build .iso.

How to handle this? :-/

Comment: @hamen: Write a script which contains the very same commands which you type on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

git would work for that, it's useful as TimeMachine/System Restore. I use it like that for my /etc dir. If it's small enough, you could push it to github, and use it as a backup and distribution mechanism.